# Stack in NASM assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, nasm

I'm trying to convert this piece c code into 64 bit nasm

```
int gcd ( int a, int b )
{
  int c;
  while ( a != 0 ) {
     c = a; 
     a = b%a;  
     b = c;
  }
  return b;
}
```

but i'm not sure where my mistake is, i thought maybe there's something about stack in assembly that i'm not aware of
this is what i did

calling

```
push word[max]
push word[min]
call gcf
pop word[num1_ones]
```

stack function

```
gcf:
    mov ebp, esp
while:
    cmp word[ebp+4], 0
    je return

    mov dx, 0
    mov ax, word[ebp+6]
    mov bx, word[ebp+4]
    div bx                                  

    mov word[ebp+4], dx         
    mov word[ebp+6], bx         

    jmp while

return:
    ret 2
```

When I run it, I get this:
[image: terminal output]

Comment: so what happens when you run it?  It looks like it should assemble.  But you don't describe what the problem is, so this isn't a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing that's missing is push/pop of EBP.

Also, are you running this in 16 or 32-bit mode?  That affects the size of the return address pushed by CALL, which affects your offsets...  Until you clarify how you build/run this, I can't say anything more specific.

I'd suggest using a debugger to look at registers/memory.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my question and I'm hoping it's a little clearer now. I'm using 64 bit nasm and I don't get any errors or segmentation faults in my code but the output i'm getting is incorrect.

Comment: @Samantha: pictures of text are much worse than actual text; you should copy/paste from your terminal into a code block to illustrate the output.

Comment: @Samantha: I'm surprised `mov ebp, esp` doesn't lead to segfaults in 64-bit mode, since you're truncating RSP down to 32 bits.  Normally the stack isn't in the low 4GB of virtual memory.  So you're probably actually building 32-bit code, but you could include the commands you use to confirm that.  It's also surprising that your program doesn't crash after your function returns, since you didn't preserve you caller's RBP

Comment: @Samantha: Either way, you should definitely use a debugger and single-step through your function while you watch register values change.  You might also be interested in a [code-golf x86 gcd function](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77364/30206), which is optimized for machine-code size (8 bytes), not for readability, but it's the exact same algorith you're using.  It keeps values in registers instead of storing/reloading to memory.  The other x86 asm answer on the same code-golf question is less optimized than mine, and more readable.